# Can i make a list comprehension out of a for loop whose output is a list whose elements depends on each other?

Tags: python, list

Is it possible to do a list comprehension of a for loop whose certain element depends on the elements made in the previous iterations of the loop? For example, say I want to do

```
a = [0,1,2,3]
out = [0]
for i in range(1,4):
    out.append(out[i-1] + a[i])
print(out)
```

Is it possible to list-comprehend this loop? Or do i need a helper function?

Comment: In your example case you probably can, but in the most general case you can't. But also beware of the unwarranted drive to list comprehend everything you come across... 1-liners just for the sake of it is not necessarily a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you also show me the most general case you are referring to?

Comment: @Len The outermost and innermost are O(1). If you care about performance, then why would you ask for a one-liner list comprehension at the first place?

Comment: @InSync List comps are a little faster than equivalent for-loops with list append() calls.

Comment: If performance is of concern, a C/C++ API should be what they are after. When someone ask for tricks and one-liner I normally take it that they want something that looks nice rather than fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this cleanly with a list comprehension alone, you can however use the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) (python ≥3.8) if you initialize the starting point:

```
i = 0
out = [(i := i+x) for x in a]
```

Or with a quite cryptic double loop:

```
out = [s for s in [0] for x in a for s in [s+x]]
```

Output: `[0, 1, 3, 6]`

This is however less explicit that the classical loop.

Better alternatives are the use of [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate), or [`numpy.add.accumulate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html):

```
from itertools import accumulate
out = list(accumulate(a))
# [0, 1, 3, 6]

import numpy as np
out = np.add.accumulate(a)
# array([0, 1, 3, 6])
```

As noted in comments, if you goal is to make the cumulated sum of the list elements, then you loop won't give the same results when the first element is not `0`. You would need to initialize `out` with `out = a[:1]` (but I don't believe this is the intended result):

```
a = [1,2,3,4]

out = a[:1]
for i in range(1,4):
    out.append(out[i-1] + a[i])
print(out)
# [1, 3, 6, 10]

i = 0
out = [(i := i+x) for x in a]
# [1, 3, 6, 10]

list(accumulate(a))
# [1, 3, 6, 10]

np.add.accumulate(a)
# array([ 1,  3,  6, 10])
```

Also note in the comments the use of `initial` parameter of `accumulate`, this however does something else. That would be the equivalent of the original loop if really the initialization is `a = [0]`:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
out = list(accumulate(a[1:], initial=0))
# [0, 2, 5, 9]
```

Comment: `accumulate()` would give a different result if the first element of `a` weren't `0` (and so does `np.add.accumulate()`).

Comment: @InSync that's true, but I believe the loop should then be initialized with `out = a[:1]`, which then gives the same result. I will make that explicit.

Comment: @mozway: you can actually to it with only list comprehension, without the walrus operator (kellybundy showed me this not long ago): see the construction in my comment.

Comment: Also, one may note that instead of manually prefixing a `0` (if that is so desired), one can use the `intial` kwarg: `list(accumulate(a, initial=0))`

Comment: @Swifty yes I've already used this kind of approach, but it's really cryptic. I'll amend my answer to add "you cannot do this "cleanly"

Comment: @user2390182 it's not exactly the same, that would be adding a constant to the addition

Comment: Yeah, I know in the very specific case the OP presented. In the general case, however, this is useful to know. The example given is kinda not minimal, as the first list element is (knowingly or not) entirely ignored.

Comment: @user2390182 exactly, I also added the example, but I doubt this is what OP really wants

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.

With a helper variable:

```py
out = [s := 0] + [s := s + e for e in a[1:]]

# or, even more stupid/cryptic:
out = [s := s + e if i else (s := 0) for i, e in enumerate(a)]
```

With [`functools.reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) (not really a list comprehension, but whatever):

```py
out = reduce(
  lambda p, c: p.append(p[-1] + c) or p,
  a[1:], [0]
)
```

With [`itertools.accumulate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) (thanks to @user2390182 for their suggestion):

```py
out = [*accumulate(a[1:], initial = 0)]
```

Obviously, these are all stupid. None of them is as clean as a good ol' loop:

```py
out = [0]

for e in a[1:]:
  out.append(out[-1] + e)
```

Comment: I don't find the `accumulate` one stupid at all, let alone "obviously" stupid. How is it stupid to use a standard function for what it is made for?

Comment: I don't find them as clean and clear as a normal loop and a colleague might ["WTF"](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/7ym547) me if I were to write such lines; that's all. Perhaps my word choice wasn't good?

Comment: If your colleague WTFs at a simple `accumulate`, get a better colleague :-)